# Bake Multiple emission material/shader nodes into one Texture?

Tags: texturing, uv, shader-nodes, procedural, emission

I've searched hard especially on Youtube, but even Ryan King Art mentioned how to bake multiple emission material into one texture. [Here, I have multiple emission material/shaders](https://blend-exchange.com/b/LsaGv1OK) I wish to bake into a single texture: